# Javascript console.log() running additional code

Tags: javascript, logging, console

I have some javascript that should print a string to the console, however it also executes another function that is defined elsewhere.  The script is:

```
var run_once = function() {
    console.log("run_once has executed.");
};

var to_print = "This should print.";
run_once();

document.getElementById("test_button").addEventListener("click", console.log(to_print));
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <button id="test_button">test</button>
        </form>
        <script src="../scripts/drill_creator.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the page is refreshed I get the following printed to the console:

```
run_once has executed.         drill_creator.js:2
This should print.             drill_creator.js:8 
Navigated to file:///C:/Users/micha/Google%20Drive/k-drills/Source/html/drill_creator.html
```

Then upon clicking the test_button, the console displays:

```
run_once has executed.         drill_creator.js:2
This should print.             drill_creator.js:8 
Navigated to file:///C:/Users/micha/Google%20Drive/k-drills/Source/html/drill_creator.html
run_once has executed.         drill_creator.js:2
This should print.             drill_creator.js:8 
Navigated to file:///C:/Users/micha/Google%20Drive/k-drills/Source/html/drill_creator.html
```

Why does run_once get called when a click occurs?  Also, why does "This should print." get printed when the page loads but the button isn't clicked?

Thanks very much

Michael

EDIT:
I have changed the last javascript line to:

```
document.getElementById("test_button").addEventListener("click", function(){console.log(to_print)});
```

Which solves the problem of the event firing on page load (thanks very much Joshua K) however this still results in run_once being called when the button is clicked.  After loading the first two lines below are displayed, then clicking the button, displays the next three:

```
run_once has executed.         drill_creator.js:2
Navigated to file:///C:/Users/micha/Google%20Drive/k-drills/Source/html/drill_creator.html
This should print.             drill_creator.js:8 
Navigated to file:///C:/Users/micha/Google%20Drive/k-drills/Source/html/drill_creator.html
run_once has executed.         drill_creator.js:2
```

SECOND EDIT:

As Joshu K mentions in the comments on his answer, the button element acts as a submit by default.  To get a button that does not trigger the form's action, but can be used to call additional javascript, one can use:

```
<input type="button" value="text on the button">
```

After making the two changes above, the code functions as I'd hoped.

Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: you are calling console.log and assigning what it returns to the click event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong: `document.getElementById("test_button").addEventListener("click", console.log(to_print));`

you don't define a callback, you call the console.log function.

Correct: `document.getElementById("test_button").addEventListener("click", ()=>console.log(to_print));`

or

`document.getElementById("test_button").addEventListener("click", function() {console.log(to_print)});`

Comment: or easier: `document.getElementById("test_button").addEventListener("click", console.log.bind(null, to_print));`

Comment: @quirimmo That is not easier just 1-2 char shorter...

Comment: @quirimmo why is this easier? Yes it's also a solution, but easier? `()=>console.log()` is pretty easy, or?

Comment: @inf3rno I find that easier, that's one of the reasons cause they invented the `bind` method. Moreover you don't define any other additional not needed function

Comment: @quirimmo that's not true. This is not a reasion why `bind` was invented and: what's wrong with defining a lambda function? `bind` also defines a _new_ function (in memory). So I cannot see the benefit of using bind over arrow function.

Comment: @quirimmo Because we are answering to somebody who does not understand the difference between a function and a function call (so probably does not even know `bind`) and you are hiding the fact that `addEventListener` requires a function argument.

Comment: The page is also reloading when you click the button, that’s why you’re seeing it twice

Comment: This explains why both are printed when the page is loaded.  It does not answer "Why does run_once get called when a click occurs?".  `console.log` returns `undefined`, so no event listener is registered.  Then you have a form with a missing `action`, which defaults to the URL of the current document.  So a POST request is sent and reloads the page.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I have changed the argument of addEventListener to ("click", function(){console.log(to_print)}) which solves the problem of it firing right away.  @nickie, I'm unsure why the event firing triggers the forms action, shouldn't that only happen when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: @MichaelCG8 a button element is meant to be a submit button! If you need a button without the abbility you can use `<input type="button">` or you have to use `evt.preventDefault()` in your javascript event handler

Comment: @JoshuaK Aaah, I see.  I thought you needed to use <input type="submit> to get that effect.  As I am wanting to use this button to trigger additional javascript but not submit the form, I will use your <input type="button"> suggestion.  It's working perfectly, thank you very much!